# Why GetxController onReady takes so long after onInit?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm writing in Flutter with GetX.

And I have a controller like this:

```dart
class TimerController extends GetxController {
  int secondsRemaining = 5;

  late Timer timer;
  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      update();
    });
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('${DateTime.now()}');
    print("onInit");
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    print("onReady");
    print('${DateTime.now()}');
    super.onReady();
  }
}
```

And using the timerController like this:

```dart
class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  TimerController timerController =
      Get.put(TimerController());

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetBuilder<TimerController>(
            initState: (data) => timerController.startTimer(),
            dispose: (_) => timerController.stopTimer(),
            builder: (controller) {
              return Text('${timerController.secondsRemaining}s');
            },
          )
  }
}
```

But it takes too long time about 2 seconds:

```bash
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /Page
[GETX] Instance "TimerController" has been created
I/flutter ( 6948): 2023-11-21 17:53:54.057766
I/flutter ( 6948): onInit
[GETX] Instance "TimerController" has been initialized
I/flutter ( 6948): onReady
I/flutter ( 6948): 2023-11-21 17:53:56.379983
```

It still slow after I comment the timer.

Why this happens and how can I solve this?